# Correlation between heavy metals and community data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, gamma-distribution, exploratory-data-analysis, environmental-data

This is a preliminary study. I want to test whether the presence of heavy metals in surface water negatively affects the benthic macroinvertebrate community.
If it's the case, I'll continue the investigation.

The main question is regarding the concentration of As:
Site 5 has a high concentration of this contaminan, and low richness and abundance.
But the data is not normal for a correlation.
What would be the appropriate statistical approach to confirm negative effects?

It's a small spreadsheet, only contains 6 sites: UPDATED FILE
[Heavymetals.xls](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WUkAu7z6SNkNPX37_UHkFOEgtrbNxN9s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Construct a correlation matrix from all the data? What are you trying to answer? Relationship between As and ...?

Comment: Ok: I can see small values of richness and abundance where arsenic value is higher (2x above legislation).
The main goal is to test if As affects negatively richness and/or abundance.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to do any kind of reasonable test for the effect of As simply because you have only one site with a high As value.  If you had three three low-As and three high-As, you'd have a better chance.  ... That being said, the data are suggestive.  The high-As site has the lowest richness, lowest abundance, lowest H, and highest J.

Comment: This can only be an exploratory exercise, as you seem to have decided your hypothesis after seeing the data.  If it had been site 6 with high *Cu* which had low  richness and abundance numbers, would your hypothesis have been different?  Once you have your hypothesis, you can use previously unseen data to test it

Comment: Henry, I can assure the hypothesis was decided before everything. 
The fact is: There is a mining site nearby, As is the possible contaminant.
So, this possible As contamination was the main reason for investigation;
I proved that there is a environmental contamination, above legislation.
And, now I want a statistical approach to test if the arsenic is bad for macroinvertebrates.

Answer (score 2):

Start with making some plots, like

[image: Abundance versus As]

and it is very clear that Site 5 is different ... If some additional evidence is needed, we can compute correlations, and compare the observed correlation with its permutation distribution, maybe. One way is

```
library(tidyverse)

 with(met, cor(Abundance, As))   
[1] -0.4893548

library(gtools)

PERMS <- gtools::permutations(6, 6, 1:6)
cordist <- apply(PERMS, 1, function(x)cor(met$As, met$Abundance[x]))
```

[image: Permutation dist of correlation]

and it is quite clear that the observed correlation of $-0.49$ is extreme in this distribution.  If you like Spearman correlation better, we can do that to:

```
with(met, cor(Abundance, As, method="spearman"))      
[1] -0.2571429

cordist.spear <- apply(PERMS, 1, function(x)cor(met$As, met$Abundance[x],
                                                method="spearman"))
```

[image: Permutation dist of Spearman correlation]

and, interestingly enough, this is very different ...